# assembly- memory addressing in x86 architecture

Tags: assembly, x86

i've got question about memory addresing, i am new to programming (especially in assembler, so please be forgiving ;)
So, if i have something like that:

```
x: db 1,2,3,4
y: dq 0
z: dq 1
```

and i have to answer what is the address of variable z, if variable x has an adress "100".

I was thinking that variable x takes addresses from 100 to 103(because i declare one byte for each value, then variable y takes addresses from 104 to 111 (because i declare quad byte (8bytes), and put zero's inside), and then comes variable z, taking addresses from 112 to 119(and put one's inside)?
Please tell me if my thinking is right, or maybe the numeration of memory cells is different? maybe i should be counting the memory cells backwards (little endian)?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Hint: you can use an assembler to verify this yourself.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with "memory addressing in x86". The answer would be the same on any architecture where a QWORD is 8 bytes. Those are just assembler directives, they don't make it to the CPU.

Comment: i'm not sure how to check the address of a variable(or should i say constant in this case), because as i said, im pretty new to this..., but still, thank you very much

Comment: The assumptions you're making are absolutely not guaranteed. An assembler could insert padding between the variables if it wanted to for alignment reasons, and anyway there's no guarantee that the values will be stored at contiguous memory locations.

Comment: Ok,  but in most basic situation my thinking is right? It was a question on my test, so i don't think my teacher would expect such wide knowledge :) and could you give me a hint how to check these addresses in assembler? This would be the most helpful, because i could check the addresses by myself

Comment: "*taking addresses from 112 to 119(and put one's inside)?*" Note that there will be just a single 1 in this 8-byte range. It's certainly not filled with multiple one's!

Comment: It is a very poor question for someone to be asking. If they are trying to test your knowledge of the meaning of `db` and `dq`, they should just ask that. The real answer to the question should have been that `db` declares bytes, which are 1 byte in size. You've got an array of 4 of them, which will be 4 bytes in length. `dq` declares a quad-word, which are 4 bytes in size. As for the hint: `mov eax, x` will put the address of `x` into the register `eax`. You can then print out the value in `eax`. Do the same for the other variables, `y`, and `z`.

Comment: I hope i didn't mix anyting in my question, but now i see that you are right, the point is how much memory each variable uses(and i hope i was right about the ranges). Thank you all again for your help, and i will surely use your hints ;)

Comment: so i checked the addresses and the variables are actually stored at contigous locations(based on their size etc) :D  but i understand that this won't happen every time, it's just idealized situation in my test-program, but i'm glad that it works ;)

Comment: @CodyGray: The bytes are guaranteed to be contiguous, with no padding, because there are no other directives.  This is assembly language, where only the bytes you ask for are assembled into the output.  Gcc does emit the gas-syntax version of this for a struct with static storage: https://godbolt.org/g/SdFQIV.  It's pretty much exactly what the OP wrote.